# Upload multipart file using Go language which is equivalent to curl request

Tags: curl, go

Following is my sample curl request.

```
curl -X POST -F 'upload=@/home/user/file.txt' 'some_url' -H 'api: api_key' -H 'callback_url:callback_url'
```

I want to do same in go language. can anyone please help me out

I have tried folowing

```
package main

import (
"fmt"
"net/http"
"io/ioutil"
"os"
"log"
)

func main() {
 data, err := os.Open("file.txt")
 if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

req, _ := http.NewRequest("POST", "url", data)
req.Header.Set("api", "api_key")

res, _ := http.DefaultClient.Do(req)

defer res.Body.Close()
body, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(res.Body)

fmt.Println(string(body))

}
```

Comment: What have you tried? Include your code. What problems did you encounter?

Comment: @Flimzy, Thanks for reply, i've edited my question

Comment: What is the problem you have with your attempt?

Comment: @Flimzy, File was not getting uploaded

Comment: Include that in your question. And explain how you know it's not being uploaded (do you get an error? What output do you see? What did you expect instead?) And check your errors.

Comment: @Flimzy, I didn't get any error, Basically i want to send file into PHP page, and if file successfully uploaded then there must be data in $_FILES array, but i am getting empty array

Comment: Check your errors. Your Go code ignores all errors, which means you're silently ignoring clues to the problem.

Answer (score -1):

```
package main

import (
"fmt"
"net/http"
"io/ioutil"
"os"
"log"
)

func main() {
    data, err := os.Open("file.txt")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    var b bytes.Buffer
    wr := multipart.NewWriter(&b)

    part, err := wr.CreateFormFile("upload", filepath.Base("file.text"))
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("do something")
    }
    _, err = io.Copy(part, data)

    wr.WriteField("api", "api_key")
    wr.WriteField("callback_url", "callback_url")

    wr.Close()

    req, _ := http.NewRequest("POST", "url", &b)
    req.Header.Set("api", "api_key")

    res, _ := http.DefaultClient.Do(req)

    defer res.Body.Close()
    body, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(res.Body)

    fmt.Println(string(body))
}
```